# html: print() embed file

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, printing, embed

I am showing a pdf inside a html using:

```
<embed id="print" src="file.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
```

I would like to create a button that prints that file.

I thought it would be something like this; but it isn't working.

```
<button onClick="javascript:document.getElementById('print').print();">
```

Anybody an idea how I can call the print function on an embedded file?

Answer (score 8):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printPDF(pdfUrl) 
{
    var w = window.open(pdfUrl);
    w.print();
}
</script>
```

You can call this function `printPDF("http://mywebsite.com/myfile.pdf")`

Comment: Thanx Agercian.
the script does open a new window, but the print() isn't doing anything.
I am using chrome to do this.

Comment: Is the PDF hosted in the same domain that the page hosting this code is?   I believe if you are trying to print from a different server it will give an 'Unsafe Javascript' message.

Comment: no the pdf is accessed form localserver, stored on my c:/ drive

Comment: printPDF is a FF addon - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/printpdf/, it does not help to resolve the question for other browsers...

Comment: Chaining the print method will work - `window.open(pdfUrl).print()`