# Link to send pdf straight to printer dialog

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, printing

I've tried the following 2 methods..

```
<embed src="assets/pdf/mypdf.pdf" id="Pdf1" name="Pdf1" hidden="true">

<a class="print" onClick="document.Pdf1.printWithDialog();"></a>

<a onClick="document.getElementById('Pdf1').printWithDialog()" style="cursor:hand;">Print file</a>
```

Another attempt..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printPDF(pdfUrl) 
{
    var w = window.open(pdfUrl);
    w.print();
}
</script>

<a class="print" onClick="printPDF("assets/pdf/mypdf.pdf");">a</a>
```

None seem to work. Any solution so I can click a link and it sends the pdf to the print dialog? window.print just brings up the actual site in the dialog, not the pdf.

Comment: Maybe look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296783/html-print-embed-file

Comment: @WesCossick: Updated my question with that solution - still not working :(

Comment: Solved thanks to Wes Cossick! Had to use single quotes within the function ()

Comment: Interesting. What if users just got sent to the PDF and then in the PDF you said "Print by pressing Ctrl+P"

Comment: Nevermind! Glad it ended up working!

Comment: @WesCossick can you share how you solved it?

Comment: @Dave is the original question asker. Looks like he used the solution above, but fixed the incorrect syntax.