# How to print a pdf using javascript in jsp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have an iframe, the contents of which are loaded from  jsp. The iframe contains a section in which i am showing a pdf . I have a button called print , which must let me print the pdf . This is the code that i have fished up after exploring stack :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printPDF()
{
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
{
document.getElementById('PDFtoPrint').print();
}
else
{
var agreement = document.getElementById('PDFtoPrint');
agreement.focus();
agreement.contentWindow.print();
} 
}
</script>

<html>
<object type="application/pdf" data="http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf" style="width:100%; height:100%" id="PDFtoPrint">
</object>
<a id="printbtn" href="#"  onclick="printPDF()">Print</a>
</html>
```

The problem is it is not working, either in mozilla or in chrome .
This is the error that i keep getting :

```
Error: Error calling method on NPObject!
agreement.focus();
agreement.print();
```

Now , i know what NPobject is . But how can i overcome this problem ? What can i do here to make it work right ?

Kindly help .

Comment: Would this help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080180/link-to-send-pdf-straight-to-printer-dialog?lq=1

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Thank you. Will it work in IE also ?

Comment: I'm not sure. You may test it.

Comment: Does not work in ie and chrome but works in mf. Any workarounds ?