# How to print a pdf in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I need to print a pdf by opening it in a new window.  I've looked at tutorials for days, but nothing is working.  I've tried many approaches, but this is the most recent:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function print()
            {
                window.getElementById("pdf").focus();
                window.getElementById("pdf").print();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="print()">
        <embed id="pdf" src="http://path/to/file" />
    </body>
</html>
```

The page loads fine, with the pdf embedded.  But it won't print, and I feel like I've been beating my head against a brick wall trying to figure this out.  How can I get this to work?  I'm willing to try anything at this point.

Comment: I don't think when you try to print a plain HTML page that it will print whats in the `embed` sections. Also, why not just make the original page link to the PDF file itself, rather than this embded PDF?

Comment: possible duplicate of [html: print() embed file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296783/html-print-embed-file)

Comment: I tried making the original page link to the PDF file, but I wasn't able to get that to work, either.

Comment: Define 'not working'. The page is a 404?